# Host Not Allowed 192...224 even though it is already in my django project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that I have pushed to docker and then a digital ocean server for live testing in a working environment. In the settings file, I have an IP address from my digital ocean server added to the allowed host portion of the settings file, but I am getting the following error:

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192...244:8000'. You may need to add '192...244' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Here is the code I have

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192...244', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
```

I didn't add the full IP, even though I have the full IP in my files.

Comment: see if this works ['192...244:8000', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']

Comment: try ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] 
PS: it's less secure if you are not firewalled off or on a public LAN
for more check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-ALLOWED_HOSTS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not terribly helpful. Please consider providing some context on what the command you propose does, why it solves the OP's problem, and what the implications of using it are.

Comment: _"ALLOWED_HOSTS This is a security measure to prevent HTTP Host header attacks, which are possible even under many seemingly-safe web server configurations... A value of '*' will match anything; in this case you are responsible to provide your own validation of the Host header"_  [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/)